# How can I execute a NodeJS program with a compiler on VSCode

Tags: node.js, virtual-machine

I have a NodeJS project that uses the "express" module, this project is in a VM (Virtual Machine), Node is installed there.

What I want is to access this folder in VSCode on my local machine (\machine_ip\c$\project_folder) and run and debug this project that is on the VM.

With this I don't need to install Node and dependencies on my local machine, but just on the VM and just edit the code on my local machine.

I tried opening the VSCode prompt and running the program normally using (npm start), but it didn't work.

Comment: I assume you've followed all the steps in the documentation? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

Comment: Thanks for this doc dude, I was needing it